# How to hide rows but not delete (like a recycle box feature)

Tags: php, mysql

I have a database setup and populated with some dummy entries and need the option to move it to recycle but not remove it. I'm starting to use relational databases and wondering the best way to do this.

Should I set a boolean field 'recycle' and query based on that or should I actually move those entries into a different table? I'm not sure how either one of these options compare to each other for performance.

Comment: Using a "recycle" field is usually how it's done.  That's how I do it :-)

Comment: see also the idea of "tombstones": http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/14402/tombstone-table-vs-deleted-flag-in-database-syncronization-soft-delete-scenari and http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tombstone_%28data_store%29

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create new new column named `deleted`. Set it for deletion. Add it to all your `WHERE` clauses:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE deleted = false
```

**DON'T** archive your rows by moving them to another table. I did that when I was a kid and a novice database designer. That's a major headache and in this day and age it won't save you anything on query time. You exponentially increase the risk of **losing data** by moving rows like that. I like to look at Propel behaviors for how to implement these. Do it this way (read this issue in regard to the deprecation warning, and ignore the warning because it is incorrect: https://github.com/propelorm/Propel/issues/810):

http://propelorm.org/Propel/behaviors/soft-delete.html

Not this way:

http://propelorm.org/Propel/behaviors/archivable.html

If you had about 1,000,000 rows in a table, then I would suggest archiving them.

Comment: Seems like PropelORM got it wrong: "Warning: This behavior [soft-delete which "hides the row"] is deprecated due to limitations that can't be fixed. Use the archivable behavior instead" while "The archivable behavior gives model objects the ability to be *copied to an archive table*" - I downvoted because the linked resources are in seeming *disagreement* with the claim. Make sure you back up your arguments in a solid fashion, pick a different resource as appropriate!

Comment: Also, this answer is *blatantly wrong* where it claims that "exponentially increase the risk of losing data by moving rows". Proper RDBMS support [ACID](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ACID) and transactions.

Comment: I am fully aware of what the Propel pages say. I've had an issue posted on their GitHub for a while now: https://github.com/propelorm/Propel/issues/810

Comment: I'm saying *pick resources that support/defend the claims* - I'm not saying that [all] the claims are wrong but rather that the linked resource does *not* support them! Since I've outlined the conflicting information (much as a teacher might due when grading a paper), take time to edit the answer to either *explain* the conflict or remove/replace/update the conflicting information.

Comment: And I'm saying that the resources _are still relevant examples_, and that anyone reading my answer will read what _I've said_ first. Also, how can you not realize that the risk of data loss will be in the **implementation of the database**?

Comment: These ACID guarantees (that even MySQL has) that have been *relied upon* to run business for the last 40+ years. There is no guesswork about the reliability of data when using databases. This answer incorrectly claims, without proper qualification, that the very act is in some way "unsafe".

Comment: You don't seem to understand that there are a lot of dumb programmers out there. Not everyone who thinks to move rows will use an `INSERT... SELECT` statement. They will copy the data to the application first, and might screw up the next INSERT. Or maybe they succeed with the INSERT but fail to DELETE, resulting in duplicate data. **Setting a Boolean is always simpler than moving a whole row.** Stop using tunnel vision, start thinking holistically.

Comment: It doesn't matter if there are "dumb programmers". Should programming forgo threads because many programmers don't understand synchronization and concurrency? Of course not! Should an approach that either moves rows (or otherwise tombstones data) be forgone because programmers don't understand transactions? Or don't write [unit-]tests? Or because programmers write code with *a lot* of bugs? Of course not! What matters is correct code (which is a culmination of many factors) - and that an *accurate* "view" of factual/reliable behavior is endowed.

Comment: All I can say is KISS. You are proposing that Lee Wise should go to the hassle of building up transactions and multiple queries, as opposed to a simple Boolean set. I didn't say you should _never_ archive rows from one table to another (I almost did). What I'm saying is that on a small database, there is nothing gained from archiving tables over soft deleting tables (dichotomy from Propel came in handy); there is only longer code. I may be wrong on the 1,000,000 row benchmark, but he won't need to archive rows unless it's a **huge** database.

Comment: I definitely am a dumb programmer but I'm trying to fix that. I think I understand the benefits and downfalls of each option. Since my table will take several years to reach even 10,000 rows I'll probably go with the 'deleted' field and revisit it in the future to see if it would be advantages to move those rows to another table.

Comment: Never say you're a dumb programmer Lee; only leads to a self-fulfilling prophecy. The fact that you asked this question instead of doing what I did when I was a kid, setting up 5 different levels of archive tables and passing the rows around in PHP, means you're on a good track to being a good programmer. I can say that _that_ kid was a dumb programmer though :P

Answer (score 1):

It depends on how often you'll need to read and create those rows, and how many there will be.

If you use the "recycle field" feature you will have to modify all queries (of course you can try renaming the original table as `table_full`, and create a VIEW of the table having only `recycle` set to *false*, but I'm not sure it will work in all foreseeable circumstances):

```
ALTER TABLE rows ADD COLUMN recycle BOOLEAN NOT NULL DEFAULT false;

ALTER TABLE rows RENAME TO rows_real;

SET @sql = CONCAT('CREATE VIEW rows AS SELECT ', (SELECT
     REPLACE(GROUP_CONCAT(COLUMN_NAME), ',recycle ', ' ') 
     FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS 
     WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'rows_real' AND TABLE_SCHEMA = 'test_db'),
     ' FROM rows_real WHERE recycle = false');
PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
EXECUTE stmt;
```

Now `INSERT`, `SELECT` and `DELETE`s with primary key work as before, so those queries need no change.

Doing it the other way you will have to worry about locking the tables during the move, and wrapping everything into transactions.

To begin, I'd favor the "one table" approach, since it looks "cleaner" to me. With proper indexing, performances shouldn't be a problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can create the column (boolean type) called e.g. `hidden`, and filter results like that:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE hidden = FALSE AND [your text]
```

You can also copy the row to another table and then remove it from the old one.  I prefer that first option.

Answer (score 0):

You've actually already answered this yourself. If you just want a hidden effect, then I too would use a `TINYINT` (or a `boolean` ofc, whatever your preference is!) field called `hidden` (imagine that!) and just set it as and when needed, then when pulling data from it. You'd just make sure you were only selecting the rows where `hidden=0`

:)

Comment: Better here will be using BOOLEAN (that's more simple :-), but TINYINT is generally the same type :-)

Comment: I'm old school, sorry. Always 0 or 1. Never true or false. I know what it means ;) Cheers! Have edited to reflect :)